# How to include FJCore into existing project?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, silverlight, fjcore

I thought it would be as easy as creating a new folder, copy-pasting source tree into it and referencing the lib from a source file. But the copied files do not show up under the new folder in Solution Explorer sidebar. Obviously there is more than that.

What do I need to do to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to click on the "Show All Files" in the Solution explorer toolbar, and then right click on the folders/files and select "Include in project".